# Some Screen Problem

Tags: login, screen, brightness, recovery-mode, add-on

first time here! I'm having a problem and I need HELP

I installed an add-on to dim my screen for the night, but the result was not so satisfying, the screen went automatically black, no way of seeing anything.

Then anytime I try to login to my user, the add-on is already running and I can't see anything, so no use for my Ubuntu anymore. Ofc, silly me, I don't remember the name of the add-on either, so I can't even search it with the "apt-cache search" command in the recovery boot. Well, I tried to search "dimmer" and "dimme", that had no result, and "dim", which had so many results I couldn't find anything useful.

Anyone have an idea about how to fix this without having to reinstall the entire Ubuntu?

Comment: have you looked at this resource? https://www.maketecheasier.com/boot-recovery-mode-ubuntu/

Comment: Well, I looked at it, turns out that my "remount tw/" doesn't exist  :V
But thank you for sharing the try  : 3

Comment: Does 'redshift' or F.Lux sound familiar.  I think you mean an installed program instead of an addon which usually is a browser extension.  Newer versions of Ubuntu might have a nightlight program already installed, not sure.

Comment: @heynnema thank you very much! I actually didn't follow those steps :V but by you telling me where the add-ons are stored, I was able to hit the "rm -r" command and send the  "oled_dimmer" to the hell it came from!
Thanks a LOT!!!

Comment: @BrunoD.Tr Great news! Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @crip659 I'm hella new at this Linux thing, so sorry if I have mistaken the names, I'll get the hang of it soon enough. But I said add-ons because it was in the add-ons suggestions in the Software Store, so :V 
Nah, anywho, problem solved, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're running Ubuntu 18.04 or newer...

- turn on the computer
- at the GRUB menu, choose `Additional Options`
- choose `Recovery Mode`, then `Root Access`
- at the `#` prompt, type:

---

```
dpkg -l *redshift*

dpkg -l *lux*
```

---

If you get an answer to either one of the above commands, note the name of the application, then type:

```
sudo apt-get purge enter-application-name-here

ie: sudo apt-get purge redshift
```

If you don't get an answer to one of the above commands, then type:

```
ls -al /home/enter-your-username-here/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

And report that output back to me as an edit to your question, and I'll tell you the next step.